# What's with all the weird writing/symbols in the hot springs in 3rei?

Tags: fate-kaleid-liner-prisma-illya

In episode 5 of Prisma Illya 3rei, we find that Gil has somehow pulled an entire hot springs out of the Gate of Babylon. The walls surrounding it have banners with a number of strange symbols and quintessentially-Japanese words on them.

You can see the symbols for yourself below; some of them are very strange, like the biohazard symbol (☣), the radiation symbol (☢), and a pair of clubs (♣) attached end-to-end. The words are "bonsai", "Mt. Fuji" (*fuji-san*), "sushi", "bushido", "[*matsuri*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsuri)", "[*kami*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kami)", "sumo", "squid" (*ika*), "[*tenshukaku*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenshu)", and "heat haze" (*kagerou*), plus one on the far-right in picture #1 that is cut off.

I have to imagine there is some sort of joke here I'm not getting. What is it?

> [image: right wall]
>  
>  [image: front wall]
>  
>  [image: left wall]

(The images are spoilered because naked-but-steam-concealed characters.)

Answer (score 4):

The banner looks similar to 武者幟 (warrior flag)

Around AD1600, There are civil war in Japan.
In that time every warrior show that flag to recognize each other.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Sekigahara) have some picture of that war.
[image: Battle of Sekigahara]

Or [some city](http://www.kanko-sekigahara.jp/en/index.html) selling that flag as goods.
[image: Flags]

These flags have name of the 将軍 (General) or [紋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mon_(emblem))(the mark of the family).

In that ilier's case, it uses same format, but it doesn't use actual mark or name.
I think it shows "Gil's wrong Japanese stereotype".